# What are the differences between ES6 class and ES5 function constructors?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I don't know the exact answer. The main difference in the constructor comes when using inheritance. If we want to create a Student class that subclasses Person and add a studentId field, this is what we have to do in addition to the above.

Comment: It changes nothing - it's 2022, use native classes.

Comment: I'd recall the only real difference between _ES6_ class and constructors was the ability to subclass native classes like Array. Currently there are more differences, like instances having private properties.